# referencing another field in a dozer custom field converter

Tags: dozer

I have 2 classes with this structure:

```
class ClassA {
  String typeA;
  List<String> valuesA;
  ... other fields go here
}

class ClassB {
  String typeB;
  List<String> valuesB;
  ... other fields go here
}
```

I need to map the valuesA to valuesB and in the custom coverter for this field mapping I need to access the typeA/typeB.

Something like: if typeA is "type1" then map valuesA to valuesB by some algorithm and if typeA is "type2" then map by a different algorithm the valuesA to valuesB.

Is this possible with Dozer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible by using the programmatic (ie in Java) custom converters of Dozer.

See the [documentation](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html), especially the TestCustomConverter Java class for an example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However, I'm not sure how to do that because it would mean to write a custom converter for the whole classA, classB mapping. I would be able to map the field, but this would override the default dozer mapper for the other fields. So I don't know how to call the base dozer converter from this custom converter to map the other fields.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to mix custom converters and XML converters, because in the Dozer config, you'll have to register a mapper for specific classes. Maybe you can solve this with some inheritance ?

Comment: Thank you, but I can't change the structure of these classes - they're generated from a specific schema that I must not change.

Comment: So, to me, you'll have to write a complete custom converter :(

Comment: But still, does this mean there's no way to solve it simpler with Dozer? Please note that I'm running inside a Spring container and I could inject the Dozer mapper in the custom converter and use it to generate the default mapping before applying the algorithms. However, I think this might run into an endless loop. Is there any other way perhaps to solve this?

Comment: As you say, you'd probably run into an endless loop. But it's worth trying it :)